# Make nested promise call in javascript

Tags: javascript

I try use **yammer SDK** `https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js` to make async call like the code below.

The **javascript SDK** doc is here `https://developer.yammer.com/docs/js-sdk`

What the code currently does is to return an Array of 50 users' profile. The total number of users is unpredictable.

What I want:
When the returned `array.length` in previous call is `equal to 50`, i.e. there could be more users in following page, make another call with `index++` to the same API URL.

This is repeated until there is no more users to be fetched.

But how to make it?

> `yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', function (resp) {
>               console.log(resp.authResponse);
>               var index = 1;
>               if (resp.authResponse) {
>                   //trigger data process
>                   yam.platform.request({
>                       url: "users.json",
>
>                       method: "GET",
>                       data: {
>
>                           "page": index
>                       },
>                       success: function (user) { 
>                           console.log("The request was successful.");
>                           console.log(user.length);
>                       },
>                       error: function (user) {
>                           console.log("There was an error with the request.");
>                       }
>                   });
>               }else{
>                   console.log("error to get access_token");
>               }
>           });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by creating a `getUsers` function and a global variable (in this case I've scoped it all through an [immediately-invoked function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) to control index you can just check if users length is 50, and if so - run the function again:

```
(function() {
    var index = 1;

    var getUsers = function() {
        yam.platform.request({
            url: "users.json",
            method: "GET",
            data: {
                "page": index
            },
            success: function (user) { 
                console.log("The request was successful.");
                console.log(user.length);

                if (user.length === 50) {
                    // There are additonal users - increment index and run the function again
                    index++;

                    getUsers();
                }
            },
            error: function (user) {
                console.log("There was an error with the request.");
            }
        });
    };

    yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', function (resp) {
        console.log(resp.authResponse);

        if (resp.authResponse) {
            //trigger data process
            getUsers();
        } else {
            console.log("error to get access_token");
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: elegant! Works like a charm, I was not confident about promise and didnt know how to wrap the call into a function... The result turned to be not complicated...

Comment: what if the call is established with call().then() format, is it similar to this answer?   I really need to learn well promise first...

Comment: @XiXiao I'm unaware of how yam creates promises - could you update your OP?

Comment: I dont quite know either. I added the SDK intro doc URL.  Microsoft has poor documentation around it, it seems the referenced js minified file is the only resource to check code..

Comment: @XiXiao Could you try out [the following](http://pastebin.com/XaZNEBQd)? My Promise knownledge is not particularly up to date, but it _should_ work.